Is Kant really a bad writer?
I am a hobbyist reader of philosophy and am quite new to Western philosophy's classics. Having started from Plato and Nietzsche, I can understand why some people label Immanuel Kant as "not a good writer." For instance, in the popular TV show Conversations with Philosophers, the host Prof. Bryan Magee classifies Kant in the same category as Hegel, and his guest Iris Murdoch agreed. However, my personal belief is that Kant, while certainly not of the same calibre as Plato or Nietzsche, is quite a brilliant writer. His introduction to a priori vs a posteriori knowledge is a beautiful description. What do others who have read Kant have to say on the subject? Is Kant really unpopular among philosophy students as a bad writer?

Derrida takes the cake. Wittgenstein and some others are way up there.

@ScottRowe +1 for debunking impenetrable nonsense!!!!!

@ScottRowe I would agree with Derrida, having read only bits and pieces here and there. But having read Wittgenstein in his entirety (TLP, PI, Zettel, and OC) I would disagree. I actually find Wittgenstein to be a deeply poetic writer. Of course his writing is in short verses, so the entirety is a bit jumbled. Its like John Searle puts it: imagine you are given parts of a toy plane but have no instructions on how to put it together! :)

I think Kant is German (and Derrida French). Thats what cooks it.  Translatability is an assumption not a fact. In my view a very colonialist assumption. See my profile page for Whorf

That can definitely be an issue, like I have no idea how people translate Hegel when he uses the full range of how his terms are used in German + occasional interpretations of his own. So that what he ends up might not have any analog in other languages without making them up.

@MarcoOcram I'd understand if you'd be speaking of Hegel (or Derrida for that matter) but in reference to Kant, your comments tell more about yourself than about the author IMHO. Yes, it helps to know some philosophy before reading Kant (especially Aristotle, Leibniz, and Hume) and it takes some effort to parse the text. But there are clear arguments that make enough sense to still be considered in many contemporary discussions.

To be fair @PhilipKlöcking I think Marco was referring to Derrida (and maybe Wittgenstein)

Yes, Kant is a famous bad writer but better than Hegel, who is a famous paranoid writer. However Derrida... Derrida is the absolute violence against thinking; I 've never seen something worse than Derrida.

Further if this question gets closed (to reuse your phrase) it tells more about this site than a hundred others upvoted

Personally I think the Derrida comments on this question are a red herring and should be expunged. Kant is obscure/hard/nonsensical/whatever has no correlation with Derrida being ... etc...

@PhilipKlöcking and Rushi, yes I was talking about Derrida- see https://www.theawfulauthor.com/blog-1/2021/7/3/vive-la-diffrence !!!

Close, this is quite subjective: while it's true that Kant is difficult to read, it is not precisely due to his writing style. Rather, it's moreover due to the historical context, the prevalent knowledge of the time, the linguistic nuances and cultural references of the era, as well as the state of the arts and sciences during his lifetime.

Questions that already got upvoted, that also already got several answers which themselves are upvoted, should not unimaginatively be labeled as "opionion-based" and should not summarily be closed by some random moderator. Implicitly the question is of course asking for reasons why people (or other philosophers) consider Kant difficult to read. So, it's a perfectly valid question.

Voted to reopen. "Is Kant a bad writer?" is opinion, but "What do others who have read Kant have to say on the subject? Is Kant really unpopular among philosophy students as a bad writer?" are questions of fact.

It is very individual how his writings are perceived, depending on the actual text version, prior knowledge, and reading competency.
I, and some of my former professors, thought that he was, without a doubt, one of the sharpest thinkers in history (ie. who wrote so that we know of them) and wrote about as concise as the complexity of his thought allowed most of the times. If you are able to parse his arguments, they are clear and the conclusions usually follow given the premises are true.
The problem with the original (German) text is that it is over 200 years old. Written in a time when writing in your native language (instead of Latin) was just about becoming en vogue, the language is very scholarly still: the sentence structure is Latin, as are the references of the subsentences to their objects. That can be hard to parse even for a native speaker. As if that wouldn't be enough, the German used is in a wording that seems odd to contemporary speakers, especially since colloquial German developed a lot in the meantime.
Accordingly, many people find it hard to parse the text and many, especially older, translations are inaccurate or even misleading. The modern Cambridge Edition translations are a big step forward, uniting a (mostly) accurate representation of the original coupled with contemporary language. Thus, reading the Cambridge Editions makes Kant easier to read and understand than reading the originals (in most cases), just like German students start to prefer modern English translations as an easier access to Hegel.
Additionally, it might help to have read Aristotle, Leibniz, and Hume, since those three are the major philosophical input and reference points in Kant's texts.
As of me, personally, I never had a problem parsing Kant in the original and always admired the beauty of his arguments. At the same time, I often encountered peers (the vast majority, actually) having these problems up to the point of giving up on trying to read Kant. Thus, I think that in a sense, both you and the opinions you refer to can be considered correct.
That said, a word of caution on French authors praising German authors: most French authors never read the originals and French translations traditionally represent the thought of the translator at least as much as they do the thought of the original author (without them knowing or even caring). That's why the "French Kant" (or Hegel) can be very different from "the German" (or English) ones. For German Idealism, Cambridge Editions in English and, interestingly, Italian translations tend to be the most truthful ones I know of.

He wrote without a doubt some of the most, if not the most, convoluted texts I’ve ever read.
Translators possibly simplify a bit. The original German is pure dread.

You never read French postmodernism or people like Adorno, did you?

It depends on what standards you apply when judging writers. I do not have an inclination to read Kant, owing to the effort required to distill his meaning - I can understand him far more efficiently by reading summaries produced by others. I have a strong dislike for any written material that is   hard to understand, as it seems to me that while the first duty of a writer is to have something important to say, the second is to say it in such a way that it has most chance of being successfully lodged in the minds of the intended audience. Kant satisfies the first duty but not the second; whereas I suspect some philosophers satisfy neither.

I've upvoted this answer.  I also wholeheartedly disagree with it. It presumes that the universe has a duty to make itself intelligible to you. I my own case the presumptions I would make are (1) the universe likely contains elements that are wildly ouside my ken (2) some ppl exist who likely get more of these things that are out of my reach. So it just may be worthwhile struggling with impenetrable material. Unfortunately, Hanlon is also inexorably true. Which makes Where do I struggle an impossible question

@Rushi you are very kind!!!

And ur a good sport Marco — albeit a physicalist one

@Rushi I probably am physicalist. I have an unimaginative tendency!
